# Android libraries/classes in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm new and currently working on a Xamarin.IOS app based on a Xamarin.Android app. I noticed that the Android native app does **background tasks** using a class called `Service` from `Android.App` and classes from `Android.Support.V7.App` and `Android.Content`. I'm just wondering if there's any similar solution for Xamarin.IOS, or do I have to do it completely from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From document [Backgrounding in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/),we know that:

> In iOS, backgrounding is recognized as an application state, and apps
> are moved in and out of the background state depending on the behavior
> of the app and the user. iOS also offers several options for wiring an
> app to run in the background, including asking the OS for time to
> complete an important task, operating as a type of known
> background-necessary application, and refreshing an application's
> content at designated intervals.

IOS regulates background processing very tightly, and offers three approaches to implement it:

- **Register a Background Task**
  If an application needs to complete an important task, it can ask iOS not to interrupt the task when the application moves into the background. For example, an application might need to finish logging in a user, or finish downloading a large file.
- **Register as a Background-Necessary Application** - An app can register as a specific type of application that has known, specific
  backgrounding requirements, such as Audio , VoIP , External Accessory
  , Newsstand , and Location . These applications are allowed
  continuous background processing privileges as long as they are
  performing tasks that are within the parameters of the registered
  application type.
- **Enable Background Updates** - Applications can trigger background updates with Region Monitoring or by listening for Significant
  Location Changes . As of iOS 7, applications can also register to
  update content in the background using Background Fetch or Remote
  Notifications .

For more details, you can check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/introduction-to-backgrounding-in-ios.